# How to force a close spider after adding a new group of markers?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I use the following libraries:

- leaflet.js
- leaflet.markercluster.js
- leaflet.subgroup.js

and my own script.

I have 3 marker types, all in a different subgroups. 11 Markers are on the same location. When I open the cluster the spider is shown, on unchecking 1 marker type, the spider is closed and the counter shows the right value. When I reopen the cluster, modified spider is shown.

Checking the marker type does not put the extra spider-marker on the screen, but also does not close the spider.

How can I force the spider to be closed?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bee-Idees kaart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup.js'></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 580px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
</body>

<script>
markers = [
  {
    "name": "Moordrecht",
    "lat": 52.019716,
    "lng": 5.183973, 
    "marker": "green"
  },

  {
    "name": "Zoetermeer",
    "lat": 52.046985,
    "lng": 4.478968, 
    "marker": "red"
  },

  {
    "name": "Gouda",
    "lat": 52.021616,
    "lng": 4.687917, 
    "marker": "green"
  },

 {
    "name": "Gouda 2",
    "lat": 52.021616,
    "lng": 4.687917, 
    "marker": "blue"
  },

{
    "name": "Gouda 3",
    "lat": 52.021616,
    "lng": 4.687917, 
    "marker": "red"
  }
];
</script>  

<script>
var iconBase = 'css\\icons\\';
// Standard fields
var groupLabel = [];
groupLabel[0] = "Red";
groupLabel[1] = "Blue";
groupLabel[2] = "Green";

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [52.021616, 4.85],
    zoom: 10
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
    subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}).addTo(map);

var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup(),
    group0 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(mcg),
    group1 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(mcg),
    group2 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(mcg),
    control = L.control.layers(null, null, { collapsed: false }), i, a, title, m; 
mcg.addTo(map);

var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
var iconName = iconBase + markers[i].marker + ".png";
var myIcon = L.icon({ iconUrl: iconName, iconAnchor:   [20, 40] }) 
var popup = '<h2>' + markers[i].name + '</h2>';

var m = L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon, title: markers[i].name} )
                  .bindPopup( popup );

    if (markers[i].marker === "red") { m.addTo(group0);} 
    else if (markers[i].marker === "blue") { m.addTo(group1); }
    else if (markers[i].marker === "green") { m.addTo(group2); }
}


control.addOverlay(group0, groupLabel[0]);
control.addOverlay(group1, groupLabel[1]);
control.addOverlay(group2, groupLabel[2]);
control.addTo(map);

group0.addTo(map); 
group1.addTo(map); 
group2.addTo(map); 

map.addLayer(mcg);

map.on('overlayadd', function() {
// How can I close the spider
});

map.on('overlayremove', function() {
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: What are the included scripts? Can you post a snippet instead?

Comment: leaflet.js / leaflet.markercluster.js / leaflet.subgroup.js and my own script.

Comment: You might need to paste the links or create a snippet. That would help us understand what is going on.

Comment: I did rework the code to some basics. 
Uncheck one of the markertypes, click the cluster and check the type back in.

Answer (score 0):

Pasted the code provided in your question into Plunker for a live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzKRs5NnrJeWfBKWOA3R?p=preview

Hum looks like you are hitting a bug in [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

When you tick in your [SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) in the Layers Control, the former will use the parent group's (`mcg` in your case) `addLayers` method [if it exists](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup/blob/v1.0.2/src/subgroup.js#L29-L30).

While MCG `addLayer` (single) [correctly unspiderfies](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/v1.3.0/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L107-L109), this step is missing in [`addLayers`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/v1.3.0/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L189-L315) (batch).

Reproducing the bug with a more simple example: https://plnkr.co/edit/G4GAjax5fi3LUqJRLLPN?p=preview (without Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup plugin)

Then it should be quite simple to fix this bug: simply unspiderfy, similarly to [how it is done in `addLayer`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/v1.3.0/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L107-L109):

```js
if (this._map && this._unspiderfy) {
  this._unspiderfy();
}
```

Updated simple example: https://plnkr.co/edit/lgvRtiRo7nh9VaWuI0RM?p=preview

Updated your code: https://plnkr.co/edit/CjjcHlZW6vpJ6075Ma3F?p=preview

Comment: Raised issue [Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster #879](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/879) for this bug.

Comment: Sent PR [Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster #922](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/pull/922) to fix this issue.